# How to write 'for-loop' function to access column and rows for repeating maths operations

Tags: matlab, for-loop, math, multiple-columns, rows

I have a .mat file of six column with hundred data each. I want to write a function which multiplies each row of first three column (B,C,D) with a 3 x 3 matrix where the matrix are in terms of sin and cos values and later include 4th row to 6th row (A, E, F) as the last column of the matrix. However, I am not getting the required output.

```
clear all
clc
[a] = xlsread('C:Desktop\Book1.xlsx')
save data a;
matObj = matfile('data.mat');
B = matObj.a(:,1);
C = matObj.a(:,2);
D = matObj.a(:,3);
DX = matObj.a(:,4);
DY = matObj.a(:,5);
DZ = matObj.a(:,6);
    rx = [1 0 0; 0 cos(B) -sin(B); 0 sin(B) cos(B)];
    ry = [cos(C) 0 sin(C); 0 1 0; -sin(C) 0 cos(C)];
    rz = [cos(D) -sin(D) 0; sin(D) cos(D) 0; 0 0 1];

for i = (matObj.a(2,:)):(matObj.a(99,:))
    r(i) = (rx*B)+(ry*C)+(rz*D);
end

%t = [A; E; F];
%T = (r, t)
```

Precisely, This provides solution when I want the solution for one row of data

```
B = 0;
C = pi/2;
D = 0;
rx = [1 0 0; 0 cos(B) -sin(B); 0 sin(B) cos(B)];
ry = [cos(C) 0 sin(C); 0 1 0; -sin(C) 0 cos(C)];
rz = [cos(D) -sin(D) 0; sin(D) cos(D) 0; 0 0 1];
r = rx*ry*rz
```

If I have several rows of these three column (B,C,D), I would like to know how to proceed.

Comment: Please post some sample data, e.g. the first ten rows of a file.

Answer (score 0):

let me get your problem straight: you have six 1x100 vectors that you want to multiply with a 3x3 matrix. (Maybe in the future, you can provide a minimal working example.)

Well anyway, that won't work. What you can do though is to create a 3x1 vector out of the matrices `[B,C,D]` and than loop through it (I am a bit irritated about your for-loop indexing. It is better to work with length()/size() to make sure that you return an integer)

```
mat = [B,C,D];
rst = NaN(size(mat,1),3); % allocate memory for speed, since Matlab stores variables coherent in your RAM
% loop over all rows
for i = 1:size(mat,1)
   rst(i,:) = ( r * mat(:,i)' )'
end
```

Okay, it is difficult to guess that size your result `rst` should look like. This has now the same size as `mat`. I have assumed that `r` is your rotation matrix of size 3x3.